# iOS fill color in view & show as animation on basis of downloading information

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

In my iOS app, I have a situation that I have to animate a view by filling a color to it as the downloading data proceeded. I am getting all the data `total downloaded data`, `current downloaded data`, but I am not able to get an idea that how to fill color in that view according to the downloaded data value. Can anyone please help me out in solving this.

I don't need a circular one, I need something like given below.

**Edit 1:** I need to do something like `Fill Horizontal` Animation shown [here](http://tympanus.net/Development/ProgressButtonStyles/)

Answer (score 0):

You can draw progress view with help of `UIBezierPath` with its method `addArcWithCenter`.

```
[bezierPath addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:startAngle endAngle:endAngle clockwise:YES];
```

Here i give you example link that will draw circular progress view with help of `UIBezierPath`.

[MHRadialProgressView](https://github.com/mehfuzh/MHRadialProgressView)

Others Progress View samples.

[Progress Samples](http://code4app.net/category/progress)

May this help you.